# Oracle query to obtain batches of rows

Tags: oracle

So here is my problem: I need to get batches of rows (select statements) for a migration to another database (other then oracle).

Suggested solution: I take batches of rows (using rowid maybe?) example:

```
batch1: 0-10000, 
batch2: 10000 - 20000,
batchn: 10000(n) - 10000(n+1)
```

So what should my query be?

```
batch1: select * from table_name where rownum >= 0 and rownum < 10000,
batch2: select * from table_name where rownum >= 10000 and rownum < 20000,
batch n: select * from table_name where rownum >= 10000*n and rownum < 10000*(n+1)
```

This does not work, (only the first select will work).

PS, I am pulling this data from a nodejs app, and thus I am sending in these batch queries in a for loop.

Comment: So you are exporting out of oracle?  You can export the records in a .csv file mapped as an external table, and just do "insert into <external_table>  select * from table_name.

Comment: Its too much of a large operation, rows > 300 million, with extensive columns.

Comment: The rownum >= ... will never work. The rownum must be <=.  It is best if you use row_number() instead and create your row ranges.

Comment: can you give an example to create a range with row_number()? Thanks!

Comment: Does your table have a `primary key` or a `unique key`?

Comment: yes it does have a primary key

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is for Oracle, why do I see MySQL tag on your question???

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate my comment:

```
-- Between rows --
SELECT * FROM 
   ( SELECT deptno, ename, sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ename) Row_Num 
       FROM scott.emp
   )
WHERE Row_Num BETWEEN 5 and 10
/
```

You may replace between operator with <= and >= if necessary.
Here's what I see in output:

```
DEPTNO  ENAME   SAL    ROW_NUM
   20   FORD    3000    5
   30   JAMES   950     6
   20   JONES   2975    7
   10   KING    5000    8
   30   MARTIN  1250    9
   10   MILLER  1300    10
```

Comment: I'm not. Query works ok. I always test my queries before posting. Make sure you copy and paste and test on small data before. And all test tables and data do exist. Also, version of Oracle matters. It is assumed you have 9 or higher version.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rownum` is not a great idea, because there's no guarantee that the same rows will be assigned the same rownum values in different queries.

If the table has any combination of columns that uniquely identify a row, it is better to generate a ranking based on that and use that ranking to identify batches of rows.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT table.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column1, column2) as my_rank
  FROM table
  )
WHERE my_rank >= 10000 AND my_rank < 20000
```

This will work with any range, and will be reproducible as long as the values in the columns used do not change and uniquely identify a row.  (Actually, I think this would be usable even if they do not uniquely identify a row, as long as they work to break the rows into small enough batches.)

The downside is that MY_RANK will be included in the output.  You can avoid that by explicitly listing the columns you do want to select; or it may be easier to filter it out when you are loading the data into the other database.

Comment: This works, but for each batch, I have to run the subquery, is there a way to save the result of the subquery and then change the outer query again and again for faster performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the rowids, use the following SQL. This SQL took 4 minutes, 20 seconds to run against a 218 million row table on a 2 CPU server with  18 GB devoted to the DB.

```
CREATE TABLE rowids
AS
    WITH
        aset
        AS
            (SELECT ROWID AS row_id, row_number () OVER (ORDER BY ROWID) r
               FROM amiadm.big_table)
    SELECT *
      FROM aset
     WHERE MOD (r, 10000) = 0;
```

After creating this table, loop through it with the following:

```
BEGIN
    FOR recs
        IN (  SELECT row_id
                   , LAG (row_id) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) prev_row_id
                   , LEAD (row_id) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) next_row_id
                FROM rowids
            ORDER BY row_id)
    LOOP
        IF prev_row_id IS NULL
        THEN
            SELECT *
              FROM big_table
             WHERE ROWID <= recs.row_id;
        ELSIF next_row_id IS NULL
        THEN
            SELECT *
              FROM big_table
             WHERE ROWID > row_id;
        ELSE
            SELECT *
              FROM big_table
             WHERE ROWID > prev_row_id
               AND ROWID <= row_id;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Second query block does not work. I get error because of line `IF prev_row_id IS NULL`. It cannot find `prev_row_id`.